# Voltage difference in electrical network

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, physics, network

Suppose we have an electrical network consisting of $n$ nodes and the graph is connected. Let $a$ and $b$ be two of the nodes. Now we put an external source at the network such that the voltage at $a$ is 1 and the voltage at $b$ is 0. Then is the maximum voltage difference between any 2 nodes in the network 1?

We can assume the degree of each node is roughly the same.

Comment: No of course not, it highly depends on the elements forming that network. Are all the elements resistors? Does the network have any sort of symmetrical properties, and so on.

Comment: @Cardinal Yes. All edges are resistors.

Comment: Is there any symmetry in the network topology?

Comment: @Cardinal Not exactly. It's just a general graph.

Comment: The voltage source is the only one, and it is applied at terminals a and b?

Comment: @Michael Yes. It is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the case where the maximum of voltage $V_{max}$ is greater than $1$.
Let $c$ be a vertex where this maximum is achieved. It is clear $c \ne a, b$.

Since voltage at $c$ is no less than all its adjacent vertices, net current flowing out from it unless all vertices adjacent to it has same voltage. By conservation of charge, this is impossible. This implies all vertices connected
to $c$ has same voltage $V_{max}$.

Since the graph is connected, there is a path connecting $c$ to either $a$ or $b$ without visiting the other. Let's say we have such a path to $a$.

$$c \to d_1 \to d_2 \to \cdots \to d_m \to a$$

Apply above arguments to $d_1$, then $d_2$ and so one, we can deduce $d_1, d_2, \ldots$ and finally $a$ has voltage $V_{max}$. Contradicting with the fact the voltage at $a$ is $1 < V_{max}$.

From these, we can conclude $V_{max} \le 1$ and hence $= 1$ (because voltage at $a$ is $1$).
By a similar argument, we can deduce the minimum of votage $V_{min}$ is $0$.

Comment: I do not get the conservation of charge part. Could you elaborate more on that? Why must the vertices connected to c has the same Vmax?

Comment: @neverevernever Let $D$ be the set of vertices adjacent to $c$. For any $d \in D$, let $V_d$ be its potential, $I_{cd}$ be the current flowing from $c$ to $d$, $R_{cd}$ be the resistance and $Q_c$ be the charge on $c$. We have $-\frac{dQ_c}{dt} = \sum_{d\in D} I_{cd} = \sum_{d\in D} \frac{V_{max} - V_d}{R_cd} \ge 0$ because $V_{max} \ge V_d$ and $R_{cd} > 0$. If any $V_d < V_{max}$, the RHS will be strictly positive and $Q_c$ will decrease in time.

Comment: Thanks! Can I also use Kirchhoff's current law which states that the net current for any node should be 0 to reason this?

Comment: @neverevernever yes, you can. Kirchhoff's current law essentially summarize the fact when the current configuration reaches equilibrium, the charge on any vertex will not change.